# How to select the latest entry from database with Ecto/Phoenix

Tags: postgresql, phoenix-framework, ecto

I'm just starting with databases and queries (coming from front-end) and I would like to select the latest entry from the fields that contain a specific `title`, say `Page1`. I know I have two fields that can help me:
1) `created_at` - I can order it an select only the latest one;
2) `id` - I know that every entry generates a new `id` so I can get the biggest `id`;
I want to apply it to the "standard" edit controller action:

```
 def edit(conn, %{"id" => id}) do
    user = Repo.get(User, id)
    changeset = User.update_changeset(user)
    render(conn, "edit.html", user: user, changeset: changeset)
  end
```

So I would like to know which method is better and to see an example of the query.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using the `id` field depends on your primary key being an integer. This may be the case currently, but will it always be the case? You can be sure that `inserted_at` will always be a time field - so I would use that. Regardless of which you use, be sure to order it in descending order so that the most recent item is first.

```
title = "Page 1"
query = Ecto.Query.from(e in Entry,
  where: e.title == ^title,
  order_by: [desc: e.inserted_at],
  limit: 1)
most_recent = Repo.one(query)
```

It is worth noting that in Ecto - by default the insertion time is captured as `inserted_at` and not `created_at` - if you have a `created_field` then you can replace `inserted_at` in my example.

Comment: Great answer. Two things: 1) You can also use the pipe expression syntax for this: `|> order_by(desc: :inserted_at) |> limit(1)`; and 2) If you have trouble with ordering closely related insertion stamps, you can declare your schema & migration to use microseconds: `timestamps([usec: true])`.

Comment: This was a very popular approach which still is suggested throughout the interwebs, but it's not idiomatic anymore and quite verbose. There is a better alternative since Jan 31, 2016. Related commits are [here](https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto/commit/c3ba2297a0b43e5fcdd6e4b863f372e496ef76e7) and [here](https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto/commit/cc92f05cb2f24c3206db9017e6c28ecf77ff100d). `Ecto.Query.last/2` is the current answer, as pointed out by @codeanpeace.

Answer (score 9):

It's also possible to accomplish this with Ecto expressions syntax and `Ecto.Query.last/2` like so:

```
alias App.Entry
import Ecto.Query

Entry |> where(title: "Page 1") |> last(:inserted_at) |> Repo.one
```

See docs for `last/2` [here](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html#last/2)!